# i can't manage file and storage services in server manager. other services are fine

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, windows

I have a windows 2012 R2 server. I had turned on the file and storage services role and was able to configure a single share in server manager. A few days later I wanted to create another share but when I select file and storage services within server manager I get the message at the top that says The server has not been queried for data since it appeared offline. Also there are no shares listed. Even though the shared folder that I already created is available from other computers.

If I try to create a file share anyway I am asked to choose a server to create the share on and the server appears in the list with a status of offline. Now this may seem like an obvious connection issue however, I am trying to configure the server locally, not over the network. I can manage other services in server manager just fine. I have WDS and WSUS roles installed and can be configured with server manager just fine. I only have a problem with file and storage services.

I tried to remove the file and storage services role from the server but as soon as I uncheck the box for file and storage services I get a pop up windows that says: 
The validation process found problems on the server from which you want to remove features. The selected features cannot be removed from the selected server. click ok to select different features. It lists validation results that simply state the name of the server and says "storage services cannot be removed."

There are no errors in the event log.

How can I get file and storage services working again?

Comment: Alright, here are some line breaks for you. It's still pretty much a wall of text though, just trying to be descriptive.

Comment: Much, much better.